# Rails routes - scope regex or redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

When integrating my project with a third party project a wild conflict appear.

I'm using the model plural as routes names, ex:

```
http://my_app/users/search (plural)
```

While they are using

```
http://my_app/user/search (singular)
```

This pattern is used for 19 different routes spread through 4 models so I don't really like to duplicate each of the routes just to support the other project.

Is there a way to use a regex or a redirection on the scopes to avoid code duplication?

Currently I have:

```
...
scope 'users' do
  get 'search'
  scope 'id' do
    get ''
    get 'ping'
  end
end
...
```

I was hoping for something like:

```
...
scope 'user(s)?' do
  get 'search'
  scope 'id' do
    get ''
    get 'ping'
  end
end
```

Or:

```
scope 'user', to: redirect('users')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scope ':pattern', constraints: { pattern: /user(s)?/ } do
  ...
end
```

Comment: there's no need to use parentheses, you can just use `/users?/` regexp